# sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?

Tags: sudo, deb, uid, lxc

I am trying to create deb package from LXC rootfs, and after creating it 
I want to install that package any computer. Up to this point I achieved 
packaging and installing deb package, however after installation of LXC
package, I cannot be superuser in that lxc. I get this error when I use
**"sudo"** command.

> sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you do a `ls -l \`which sudo\`` ?

Comment: Just run that command and post the output.

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 121144 Sep  4 07:11 /usr/bin/sudo

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I just had this same exact problem on Mac OS after strangely deciding to screw my own system by doing: `sudo chmod -R /usr/bin`. If that's someone else's case just open **Disk Utility**, select your OS disk ("Macintosh HD" in my case), go to **First Aid** tab then hit **Repair Disk Permissions**, wait a few and things should get fixed.

Comment: Thanks - I was facing this exact issue, and your answer helped me solve it!

Comment: Awesome. This worked for me, after the accepted answer didn't seem to do anything. Thanks!

Comment: This answer should be on top!

Comment: I did the same, but Repair Disk Permissions doesn't work for me... any ideas?

Answer (score 15):

Your `sudo` binary doesn't have the `setuid` flag, as it correctly guessed. As root, try:

```
chmod u+s /usr/bin/sudo
```

---

## OSX users:

To everyone landing here from search engines: **this is not the way to fix the OSX system that you broke**. The question is Linux oriented - **hint, lxc tag** - and that is what this answer is for. The answer provided by Gustavo Matias might help :-)

Comment: I get the message:
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/usr/bin/sudo’: Operation not permitted

Comment: this solution is not working for me getting: 'chmod: changing permissions of ‘/usr/bin/sudo’: Operation not permitted'

Also I am getting '-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 121144 Feb 28  2013 /usr/bin/sudo' when I run ls -l `which sudo`

Comment: @holyredbeard Check the tags on this question again. This is not an OSX specific question and as such there is nothing OSX specific in my answer :-)

Comment: I accidentally messed /usr/bin permission and you saved me to reinstall my CentOS server. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @cnicutar How does this work? If I run the command without `sudo`, it tells me I don't have permission, and if I run it with `sudo`, it gives me the same "effective uid is not 0..." error (I'm using Amazon Linux).

Answer (score 2):

@cnicutar has provided the answer

On a Ubuntu 14.04 host, the following worked

```
    Exit the container
    Stop the container
```

Now that you are on the host, set the flag

```
sudo chmod u+s /var/lib/lxc/<container_name>/rootfs/usr/bin/sudo
```

Check the flag

```
sudo ls -l /var/lib/lxc/<container_name>/rootfs/usr/bin/sudo
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root ... ... var/lib/lxc/<container_name>/rootfs/usr/bin/sudo
```

Start your container and enter the console
You should be able to execute

```
sudo apt-get install <package>
```

Answer (score 1):

This error can also be caused by the use of jailed ssh shell for the user. Try un-restricting the shell session if this is the case.

Comment: Care to elaborate or reference a source?

Answer (score 0):

I had this proplem today,and I solved this by **run following command with root**

```
chmod u+s /usr/bin/sudo
```

I hope it will help you !

Answer (score 0):

if it's still actual I was using docker 16 and it had a bug
[docker issue](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/#4161:%7E:text=Fixed%20sudo%20inside%20a%20container%20failing%20with%20a%20security%20related%20error%20for%20some%20images.%20Fixes%20docker/for%2Dmac/6675%20and%20docker/for%2Dwin/13161.) 
so just updating the docker based driver to 16.1 is helped for me !