# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'.

Tags: mysql, linux, sockets

Tried all posts for solution . 
[ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run)

[ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock' (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658891/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run)

[Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (38)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38)

During Follow ups got another issue..
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?

So for this Tried following post

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2222715

[sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607003/sudo-effective-uid-is-not-0-is-sudo-installed-setuid-root)

Also got this 
chown: changing ownership of `/usr/bin/sudo': Operation not permitted

anybody give perfect solution for this..
Except re-installing OS.. I don't have rescue disk for recovery.

Comment: How you're connecting to mysql , using command line ? if yes please provide the command which you're using. Also tell us what OS is that.

Comment: yes i'm connected using command line on linux..
I'm using this command mysql -uroot -p

Comment: okay and what is mysql service status `/etc/init.d/mysql status` ?

Comment: Did you try with restarting mysql services ? Also what is the output of `netstat -pan | grep 3306` command ? What OS is that BTW ?

Comment: Its Ubuntu

O/p
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)

Comment: I m not able to start/stop services.

Comment: How did you installed, give output of this mysql `dpkg --list | grep mysql`

Comment: dpkg --list | grep mysql
ii  libdbd-mysql-perl                        4.021-1                                   amd64        Perl5 database interface to the MySQL database
ii  libmysqlclient18:amd64                   5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.10.1                   amd64        MySQL database client library
ii  libmysqlclient18:i386                    5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.10.1

and more..

Comment: Can you try wth installing mysql again `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` ?

Comment: Already mentioned anything related to sudo is not working...

sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root? this error comes..

I think the problem is related to ownership of files...

Comment: If you have root access then please just install sudo and fix this permission related issue and then try. As mysql status as stop. there is no way you will be able to connect mysql database, so you need to make that service running first.

Comment: sudo is installed already, but its ownership is not root... and i'm not able to change ownership.. 

output of ls -l /usr/bin/sudo is

-rwxr-xr-x 2 site site 112888 Jul 16  2012 /usr/bin/sudo

and when i change its permission it says sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to stop your mysql server and restart it again.

> ```
> /etc/init.d/mysql  stop
> /etc/init.d/mysql  start
> ```

Still same issue then rename `mysql.sock` file from mysql directory e.g. `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` folder and restart mysql server.

Comment: /etc/init.d/mysql  stop --->  says Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service mysql stop

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the stop(8) utility, e.g. stop mysql

when i use stop mysql or service mysql stop it shows unknown instance

Comment: Are you able to stop or start mysql using any of the below command.. `/etc/init.d/mysql start`  `/etc/init.d/mysqld start`  `service mysql start`  `service mysqld start` ??

Comment: status mysql shows  mysql stop/waiting.

service mysql start shows
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.30" (uid=1000 pid=2209 comm="start mysql ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")

Comment: /etc/init.d/mysql start shows

Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service mysql start

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the start(8) utility, e.g. start mysql
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.34" (uid=1000 pid=2223 comm="start mysql ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")

Comment: @VarunChawla... you need to stop mysql forcefully run below command and get hte pid of mysql and kill them... `ps -ef |grep mysql.sock`  then kill pid using `kill -9 pid`

Comment: ps -ef |grep mysql.sock
ravi      3129  2992  0 12:09 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql.sock

kill -9 3129
-bash: kill: (3129) - No such process

Comment: Do you know the base directory of mysql?? if yes then go to base directory of mysql and rename `mysql.sock` file to `mysql.sock.bk' and start mysql server.

Comment: already mentioned not able to start/stop mysql server...

I think the problem is related to ownership of files.

output of ls -l /usr/bin/sudo is 

-rwxr-xr-x 2 site site 112888 Jul 16 2012 /usr/bin/sudo and when i change its permission it says sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root? can you help me regarding that. I want to change ownership to root

Comment: Let me know you are the owner of the your linux system.. or you are using the shared linux system ?? If you have root level user for linux then you can set the permission for the same... you can set the default permission with a simple command on linux if you have root level user.

Comment: yes i am the owner of linux system. Actually i have mount my disk to another system due to some system issue. and run all work using that system. Now when i mount that disk to previous system, it has lost its ownerships. it is not showing the ownership of root.

Comment: open a  new terminal and run the below command to restore the ownership of FileSystem. `touch /.autorelabel; reboot` this will reboot your system and relabel all file system.