# sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root? (on mac os x 10.12)

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, sudo

So I'm a bit of a terminal noob so bear with me but I was trying to update brew to install something, so I ran: `brew update` and got `Error: /usr/local must be writable!`

Wasn't really sure what that was about so I tried running `sudo brew update` and got `sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?`

Not sure if this helps but running `ls -l $(which sudo)` gave me:

```
ls: is: No such file or directory
ls: is: No such file or directory
ls: is: No such file or directory
ls: is: No such file or directory
ls: sudo: No such file or directory
ls: sudo: No such file or directory
ls: sudo: No such file or directory
ls: sudo: No such file or directory
-r-s--x--x  1 root        wheel  369136 Sep 13 20:56 /usr/bin/sudo
-r-s--x--x  1 my_profile  admin  168448 Jan 13  2016 /usr/local/bin/sudo
-r-s--x--x  1 my_profile  admin  168448 Jan 13  2016 /usr/local/bin/sudo
-r-s--x--x  1 my_profile  admin  168448 Jan 13  2016 /usr/local/bin/sudo
```

I tried the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607003/sudo-effective-uid-is-not-0-is-sudo-installed-setuid-root) (using Disk Utility and running First Aid) but it didn't seem to have any effect....

Can anyone tell me what's going on and what I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `ls -la /usr`, the result most likely will be something like below:

`total 0
drwxr-xr-x@   11 root  wheel    374 Oct 14 14:35 .
drwxr-xr-x    32 root  wheel   1156 Oct 26 09:49 ..
drwxr-xr-x    19 root  wheel    646 Oct 10 18:51 local
... (some other files and directories)`

Now it's obvious from the above that unless you are logged in as a `root` or your user is in the `wheel` group (which is most likely not), any command you issue with your user which needs write permission (such as `brew update`) will fail.

One of the possible solutions (and I am not claiming is the best one) would be to change permissions of `/usr/local`.

Like so:

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local`

Interestingly enough, if you then run

`brew update`

all goes well and you get the following message:

`=> Migrating HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY (please wait)...
==> Migrated HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY to /usr/local/Homebrew!
Homebrew no longer needs to have ownership of /usr/local. If you wish you can
return /usr/local to its default ownership with:
  sudo chown root:wheel /usr/local`

Which I guess explains what happened in the first place.

Hope that helps.