# Loading a SSL certificate to container's JVM

Tags: java, docker, ssl, kubernetes

I have a Helm Chart. Which on deployment creates the following Kubernetes resources:

1. A SSL enabled Service
2. A Container created with my Docker image which internally runs a Java process that communicates with the above service.
3. Kubernetes Secrets (SSL certificates and access keys), that are mounted inside the above container.

The problem is my Container can not talk to my Service unless I add the SSL certificate to Java certificates. I do this by running the following command **manually** inside my docker with **root** user.

```sh
cd ${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/security 

keytool -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -trustcacerts -importcert -alias myservicecert -file /home/myuser/.myservice/certs/public.crt
```

I want to automate the above steps but facing issues:

- I can not perform above steps inside the `Dockerfile` since the certificate is not available at that time. Obivious.
- I can not add these steps in `entrypoint.sh` file of the docker because entrypoint file is executed by a different user than the root.
- Another solution that I could think of is that change the permission of path `${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/security/cacerts` to `777` so that I can run these commands in `entrypoint.sh` without an issue. But I am not sure if this is the correct way to go due to security reasons. Suggestions on this ?
- I do not want to set a custom location for certificates using `Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore` because then java will not have access to root certificates.

What is correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

### TL;DR

You can add the certificate to the keystore in an [`initContainer`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/). The keystore can be shared between the `initContainer` and the `container` using a [`volume`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/).

---

In this example we're mounting the `tls-secret` to the pod as a Kubernetes [Secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/). The `tls-secret` contains the `tls.crt` which needs to be added to the keystore. We add the certificate to the keystore in the `initContainer` after copying the security files into a `volume` which is mounted to the pod's `container`.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapp
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  containers:
  - name: myapp
    image: openjdk:8-jdk-slim-buster
    command:
    - bash
    - -c
    - |
      keytool -list -keystore /usr/local/openjdk-8/jre/lib/security/cacerts -alias local
      sleep infinity
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /usr/local/openjdk-8/jre/lib/security
      name: cacerts
  initContainers:
  - name: init-cacerts
    image: openjdk:8-jdk-slim-buster
    command:
    - bash
    - -c
    - |
      cp -R /usr/local/openjdk-8/jre/lib/security/* /cacerts/
      keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias local -file /security/tls.crt -keystore /cacerts/cacerts -storepass changeit
      keytool -list -keystore /cacerts/cacerts -alias local
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /cacerts
      name: cacerts
    - mountPath: /security
      name: tls
  volumes:
  - name: cacerts
    emptyDir: {}
  - name: tls
    secret:
      secretName: tls-secret
      defaultMode: 0400
```

[image: shared keystore]

Comment: It will replace the original `cacerts` with the one from `init-container` right ? So any additional certificates added by base image will be lost.

Comment: Yes. Just an example. Can mount and add all the certs you want.

Answer (score 2):

Recently, I faced a problem like that, and my solution was based on @masseyb, but slightly different, I had an Elasticsearch deployment wich cannot update GeoIp internal database without a self signed certificate of my company.

To solve this, I configured and init container with the company official image (which includes all certificates inside `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`, then installed openjdk (this will automatically create a new keystore), and finally, copied only the cacerts file (elasticsearch use other files inside the /usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk/lib/security/cacerts so we have to point a `subPath`)

```
kind: StatefulSet
apiVersion: apps/v1
[...]
      containers:
      - name: elasticsearch
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.10.1
[...]
        - name: mount-certificates
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk/lib/security/cacerts
          readOnly: false
          subPath: cacerts
[...]
      - name: fix-certificates
        image: company.registry/ubuntu-customized-image-with-certs:latest
        command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - |
          apt-get update --yes
          apt-get install openjdk-17-jdk --yes
          cp /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts /certificates-ubuntu/
          echo "certificates in java keystore:"
          keytool -list -keystore /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mount-certificates
          mountPath: /certificates-ubuntu
          readOnly: false
      volumes:
[...]
      - name: mount-certificates
        emptyDir: {}
```

Comment: the problem with this is that the initContainer needs to run as root

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to allow running the `keytool` command using sudo.

You may need to install sudo in your Dockerfile and then you can set up `/etc/sudoers` to allow the user running `entrypoint.sh` to run that specific command (without a password). Have a look at [this answer on Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/215419/110479) for how to do it.

All you need to do then is locate the certificate and run

```
sudo keytool -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -trustcacerts -importcert -alias myservicecert -file /home/myuser/.myservice/certs/public.crt
```

In `entrypoint.sh`

Alternatively you can install a script when building your container that sets up the certificate and installs it and allow *that* to be run with sudo. That way you don't open up the possibility to add more certificates if someone gains access to the container

Comment: I did install `sudo` in Dockerfile and modified `/etc/sudoers` accordingly. But i still can't run any command with `sudo` option. Some restriction put by base image may be. ERROR : `effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?`

Comment: Sounds like something is off with your system. Search for the error and see if you can find a solution. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607003/sudo-effective-uid-is-not-0-is-sudo-installed-setuid-root) one possible solution.