# Self-Hosted GitHub Runner: Error when running sudo "sudo: effective uid is not 0..."

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, github-actions, runner

I am trying to run self-hosted GitHub runners in a K8s cluster [using actions-runner-controller](https://github.com/actions-runner-controller/actions-runner-controller). Whenever I run a  workflow on the runner and attempt to use `sudo`, it fails with the following error: `sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?`
I have created the `runner` user and added it to the sudo group with the following commands in my dockerfile. I have also made sure to set the permissions for the location where sudo is installed.

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo \
    && adduser --disabled-password --gid 0 --gecos "" --uid 1001 runner \
    && groupadd docker \
    && usermod -aG sudo runner \
    && usermod -aG docker runner \
    && echo "%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers \
    && chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo \
    && chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo \
    && chmod u+s /usr/bin/sudo
```

In my runnerdeployment.yaml, I have tried multiple different settings for trying to get the runner to be able to run sudo. Including;

- setting RUN_AS_ROOT to both `true` and `false`
- Setting RUNNER_ALLOW_RUNASROOT to both `1` and `0`
- Having securityContext.runAsUser set to `1001` (uid of runner user) and not having it set

Nothing has seemed to help, and I have tried everything I've seen from other SA posts about the same error `sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?`

Running `mount` does not show `/usr/bin/sudo` or `/` with the nosuid bit set, here's the output from some commands I have seen on other posts about this error:

```
> df `which sudo` 
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
overlay        129886128 26817760 103051984  21% /
> whomami
runner
> groups
root daemon sudo docker
> id
uid=1001(runner) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),1(daemon),27(sudo),1000(docker)
```

I am unsure what else to try to fix this issue.

Host OS is ubuntu-20.04 focal.
`ls -l /usr/bin/sudo` shows

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 166056 Jan 19  2021 /usr/bin/sudo
```

A few of the other posts I've looked at:

[sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607003/sudo-effective-uid-is-not-0-is-sudo-installed-setuid-root)

https://superuser.com/questions/1580293/sudo-effective-uid-is-not-0-is-usr-bin-sudo-on-a-file-system-with-the-nosuid

https://superuser.com/questions/897284/sudo-effective-uid-is-not-0-is-sudo-installed-setuid-root-for-normal-users

https://askubuntu.com/questions/625540/suddenly-cant-run-sudo

Dockerfile Config:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

COPY --from=installer-env ["/actions-runner", "/actions-runner"]

# Set env vars
ENV RUNNER_WORKDIR "/_work"
ENV GITHUB_TOKEN ""
ENV RUNNER_SCOPE ""
ENV REPO_URL ""
ENV ORG_NAME ""
ENV RUNNER_NAME_PREFIX ""
ENV LABELS ""
ENV DISABLE_AUTOMATIC_DEREGISTRATION ""
ENV RUNNER_OPTIONS ""
ENV RUN_AS_ROOT "true"
ENV RUNNER_ALLOW_RUNASROOT=1
ENV RUNNER_TOOLS_DIRECTORY=/opt/hostedtoolcache
ARG GOSU_VERSION=1.10-1
COPY ./github-runner/user.sh ./github-runner/runnertoken.sh ./github-runner/entrypoint.sh /actions-runner/
COPY ./github-runner/startup_script.sh /usr/local/bin/

WORKDIR /actions-runner

# RUN
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo \
    && adduser --disabled-password --gid 0 --gecos "" --uid 1001 runner \
    && groupadd docker \
    && usermod -aG sudo runner \
    && usermod -aG docker runner \
    && echo "%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers \
    && chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo \
    && chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo \
    && chmod u+s /usr/bin/sudo

RUN ./bin/installdependencies.sh \
    && mkdir -p ${RUNNER_WORKDIR} \
    && mkdir -p ${RUNNER_TOOLS_DIRECTORY} \
    && chown -R runner ${RUNNER_WORKDIR} /actions-runner ${RUNNER_TOOLS_DIRECTORY} /usr/local/bin/startup_script.sh \
    && chmod +x /actions-runner/runnertoken.sh /actions-runner/entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/startup_script.sh

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y jq gosu=${GOSU_VERSION} 2>&1 \
    # Clean up
    && apt-get autoremove -y \
    && apt-get clean -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Add premissions to runner user


ENTRYPOINT ["/actions-runner/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: What is your host OS? What is the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/sudo`? What file systems are the layers of the `overlay` filesystem? Show the docker configuration. Add links to the posts you already checked.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add all requested information or clarification to the question.

Comment: @Bodo added the information to the main question

Comment: Are the permissions of `/usr/bin/sudo` wrong when you don't run the `chown` and `chmod` commands? Maybe related to `allowPrivilegeEscalation` (see https://github.com/wodby/mariadb/issues/5#issuecomment-394069800, https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/  Why do you need `sudo`? Maybe there is a different solution to fix permissions problems. You should explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: Permissions for sudo are wrong when the `chown` and `chmod` commands are not used. `allowPrivilegeEscalation` didn't seem to work but that was a good recommendation, thank you.

The main reason why want to be able to use sudo is the chance that the user runs an action that requires it.